# How to apply styling for a checkbox in lighting:recordform

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I saw your blog on how to apply styling for a checkbox for a lightning component using CSS but I tried on a lightning:recordform but unable to change the color of background color of a checkbox. Here is my component code

CODE ---

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" access="global">

 <aura:attribute name="InputFields" type="list"/> 
 <aura:attribute name="InputTitle" type="string"/>  
 <aura:attribute name="IconName" type="string" default="utility:chevrondown"/>    
 <div class="slds-box parent">      
 <h3 class="slds-section__title  test-id__section-header-container" data-aura-rendered-by="344:1408;a">    
        <button aria-controls="toggle" id="toggle" aria-expanded="true" class="slds-button slds-section__title-action" onclick="{!c.toggle}" >
          <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.IconName}" class="slds-p-right_x-small" aura:id="swithcicon" width="100%" Height="100%" default="utility:chevrondown" size="X-small"  alternativeText="Expand"/>
              <span class="test-id__section-header-title slds-truncate" title="{!v.InputTitle}">{!v.InputTitle}</span>
        </button>
    </h3>
    <div class="slds-form parent" role="list">    
    <div class="slds-grid full forcePageBlockSectionRow">
        <div class="slds-has-flexi-truncate slds-p-horizontal_x-small full forcePageBlockItem forcePageBlockItemView">
            <div aura:id="showhidefields" class="slds-show">
                            <lightning:recordForm 
                             recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
                             objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}" 
                             fields="{!v.InputFields}"
                             columns="2"
                             mode="readonly"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
</aura:component>
```

CSS CODE-->

```
/* For checkbox background */
.THIS.parent.slds-form-element .slds-form-element__control .slds-checkbox .slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox--faux{
    background : yellow;
}
/* For checkbox marker color */
/*.THIS.parent.slds-form-element .slds-form-element__control .slds-checkbox .slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox--faux:after{
   border-color: #dcff1b;
}*/
```

Comment: have you tried changing the scope of your CSS ? this is most likely the issue. When  dealing with CSS, if you are unsure of the scope, Try changing it

Comment: Not sure when you say change the scope. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
.THIS .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox][disabled]+.slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox_faux {
        background-color: rgba(201, 199, 197, 0.96);
}
```

This should work. It allows you to override the checkbox default `Background-color.`

Comment: while recommending any solution be descriptive. what is causing the issue and how your solution will solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
.THIS lightning-input-field > lightning-input > div > label{
    background-color: red;
}
```

you might want to read a bit on the following topic:

[CSS element>element Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)

Notice that the above targets ALL Label fields within the Form Element that follow the specified hierarchy.

If you are not sure what that means, might want to check some CSS tutorials online.

Comment: The issue is anything inside that <lightning:recordform fields are generated dynamcially and checkbox is part of it. It shows by default gray background which is hard to see for the users. I tried above but do not see any change to the checkbox element at all.

Comment: CSS rules still apply to dynamically created fields

Comment: I have tried but no luck on having any change in the checkbox.